# Use gsub to insert double quotes in ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to convert `"foo&bar"` to `"foo","bar"`.

I am trying to do this with gsub, but not having any luck..

```
2.3.0 :036 > string = "foo&bar"
 => "foo&bar"
2.3.0 :037 > string.gsub("&", "\"")
2.3.0 :038?>
```

I have tried all manner of escaping special characters.

Comment: Do you want an array of ["foo", "bar"]

Comment: `"foo&bar".gsub("&", "\",\")`

Comment: `str.scan(/\w+/)` is another option

Comment: str.split('&').join('","')

Comment: If `"foo&bar"` is a string, what is `"foo","bar"`? Two strings separated by a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go

```
2.2.3 :008 > string = "foo&bar"
 => "foo&bar" 
2.2.3 :009 > string = string.split('&')
 => ["foo", "bar"] 
2.2.3 :010 > string.to_s
 => "[\"foo\", \"bar\"]" 
2.2.3 :013 > string.to_s.gsub(/\[|\]/,'')
=> "\"foo\", \"bar\""
```

**Updating for performance**

As my friend @engineersmnky said in the comments, double gsub is better, he is right. However there is a even better way for performance. See this benchmark below.

```
require 'benchmark'

TO_TEST = 'foo&bar'.split('&').to_s * 999999

def replace_with_regex
  puts 'replace_with_regex: ' + (Benchmark.realtime { TO_TEST.gsub(/[\[\]]/, '') }).to_s
end

def replace_no_regex
  puts 'replace_no_regex: ' + (Benchmark.realtime { TO_TEST.gsub('[', '').gsub(']', '') }).to_s
end

def replace_with_delete
  puts 'replace_with_delete: ' + (Benchmark.realtime { TO_TEST.delete('[]') }).to_s
end
```

**Results**

```
replace_with_regex: 0.48356830099987747
replace_no_regex: 0.29740285399998356
replace_with_delete: 0.0289891009999792
```

So you should use `.delete('[]')`

Comment: Good call. I got stuck on trying to use gsub rather than considering something like split!

Comment: @Lumbee I edited last gsub to use regex, so it's faster

Comment: @RamonMarques as a note the double substitution is actually faster than the regex one.

Comment: @engineersmnky you are right. Updated my answer. And just saw your answer after I updated lol!

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in `gsub` or for anyone who ends up here these will all do the trick

```
  str = "foo&bar"
  str.gsub(/^|&|$/) {|m| m.empty? ? "\"" : "\",\""}
  #=> "\"foo\",\"bar\""
```

This uses the block form of `gsub` in which each match is passed into the block individually so `^` (beginning of line) results in a match of `''` (an empty string) as does `$` (end of line). For these matches we sub in `"\""` (a double quote). The only other match is `&` so in this case we sub in `"\",\""` (a double quote, then a comma, then another double quote).

Not sure if your actual use case is more specific than this if so please provide other examples

Other fun ways (using `gsub`)

```
 str.gsub(/^|&|$/,{""=>"\"","&" => "\",\""})
 #=> "\"foo\",\"bar\""
 str.inspect.gsub("&","\",\"") #<---- extremely fast
 #=> "\"foo\",\"bar\"
```

If performance is a concern here's how the suggested methods play out:

```
require 'fruity'
compare(
  # Ramon Marques original answer (note this has an extra space)
  double_sub: ->{string.split('&').to_s.gsub('[','').gsub(']','')},
  # Ramon Marques updated answer (note this has an extra space)
  regex_sub: ->{string.split('&').to_s.gsub(/\[|\]/,'')},
  # Options provided above 
  inspection_sub: ->{string.inspect.gsub("&","\",\"")},
  regex_no_split: ->{string.gsub(/^|&|$/,{""=>"\"","&" => "\",\""})},
  regex_no_split_block: ->{string.gsub(/^|&|$/) {|m| m.empty? ? "\"" : "\",\""}}
)
Running each test 1048576 times. Test will take about 8 minutes.
inspection_sub is faster than regex_no_split_block by 60.00000000000001% ± 10.0%
regex_no_split_block is faster than regex_no_split by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
regex_no_split is faster than double_sub by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0% (results differ: "foo","bar"
 vs "foo", "bar")
double_sub is faster than regex_sub by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for:

```rb
'"foo&bar"'.gsub('&', '","')
```

```rb
irb(main):001:0> string = '"foo&bar"'
=> "\"foo&bar\""
irb(main):002:0> puts string.gsub('&', '","')
"foo","bar"
```

Comment: The accepted answer shows that the initial input has no quote marks within the string.